# RabbitMQ Spring Boot + Angular How do i subscribe in Angular to a publisher in spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rabbitmq

i set up a Rabbitmq publisher and a listener in spring boot and all works but i cant subscribe to the queue i publish via spring boot in angular. My Endgoal is to do something in the frontend as soon as the publisher publishes something. In the frontend, as soon as i get a new queue, i want to make a desktop notification.

Any suggestions? Right now when i do it, it gives me:

*"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: amqp.connect is not a function"*

```
  async receiveMessages() {
    var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
    await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function (error0: any, connection: any) {
      if (error0) {
        throw error0;
      }
      connection.createChannel(function (error1: any, channel: any) {
        if (error1) {
          throw error1;
        }
        var queue = 'hello';

        channel.assertQueue(queue, {
          durable: false,
        });
        channel.consume(
          queue,
          function (msg: any) {
            console.log(' [x] Received %s', msg.content.toString());
          },
          {
            noAck: true,
          },
        );
      });
    });
  }
```